# How to use the css and js file from the vendor folder in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like to involve jQuery Smart Wizard in my application.
I have update the composer.json and then run composer update.
Here I get the related files in the vendor folder as techlab\smartwizard.

How could I link the css and js file from the twig template?
I have tried to use below command to generate link to the resources.

```
php bin\console assets:install --symlink --relative
```

It seems that the command only deal with the folder in resources\Public in each Bundle.
I hope I could use some link as below to get the files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/XXX/static//styles/XXX.css') }}">
```

I know I could create CSS and JS folder under web folder and then copy the related files there. I just wonder if I have to do this manually then why I use composer to install it. I could just download the file and put them in the target folder. That's all.

I am not sure if there is some better way to manage the resource.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [Creating css, js, image like assets in a symfony application and accessing them in twig template](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/qau5/creating-css-js-image-like-assets-in-a-symfony-application-and-accessing-them-in-twig-template)

Comment: Helps a lot, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assets:install` command works only if it finds directories/files in `Resources/public` directory.

I see two options here:

```
1) create a bundle and add the files in the Resources public directory

2) use bower and install this package as a dependency for frontend. 
For this, you may create a `.bowerrc` file to set the 
target directory which can be `web/bower`.
```

Composer is used to manage php dependencies, not frontend ones, except somebody made a package to work with composer and to be integrated in framework.

So, you can use:

```
1) composer -> php related, backend dependencies

2) bower, npm -> frontend dependencies
```

I use a precompiler with gulp that manages css, images and js files in the project

Comment: Thanks Marius. Currently I just use the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php bin\console
```

To

```
php bin/console
```

Where in your command line

Comment: Not only off topic but does not works so well on windows.